# (C#) How to determine whether it is an enum type using Mono.Cecil?

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

How to determine whether it is an enum type using Mono.Cecil??

It's easy to determine just using Type.IsEnum. But I can not find any similar functions in TypeDefinition...

Is there any way to determine?

Comment: There does seem to be a `IsEnum` property on `TypeDefinition`. See [here](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/master/Mono.Cecil/TypeDefinition.cs#L408). If your version does not include this, you could write an extension method which does the same as the source

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an `IsEnum` property on `TypeDefinition`.

Oh, and before you ask your next question, here's how you parse an enum string back to it's int value, using Cecil...

```cs
int ParseEnum(TypeReference enumRef, string value)
{
    var enumDef = enumRef.Resolve();
    if (!enumDef.IsEnum)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();

    int? result = null;

    foreach (var v in value.Split(',')) {
        foreach (var field in enumDef.Fields) {
            if (field.Name == "value__")
                continue;
            if (field.Name == v.Trim())
                result = (result ?? 0) | (int)field.Constant;
        }
    }

    if (result.HasValue)
        return result.Value;

    throw new Exception(string.Format("Enum value not found for {0}", value));
}
```